# JSON sort by specific value - PERL

Tags: json, perl, sorting

i have this example code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::PP qw( );
use Data::Dumper qw (Dumper);


my $json = JSON::PP->new()->pretty->utf8;       # lesbares JSON | Sort numerically
my %ORDER = (id => 1, name => 2);

 $json->sort_by(sub {
    ($ORDER{$JSON::PP::a} // 999) <=> ($ORDER{$JSON::PP::b} // 999)
    or $JSON::PP::a cmp $JSON::PP::b
});

print $json->encode(
[
    {name => 'ABS700', id => 0, data => [
            {
                dmsg => 's4F038300', state => 'T: 3.3', user => 'SD_Protocol'
            }
        ]
    },
    {name => 'GT-WT-02', id => 0, data => [
      {
                dmsg => 's5410AC5F9800', state => 'T: 17.2 H: 47', user => 'Ralf9'
      }
    ]
    },
    {name => 'NEU', id => 99, data => [
      {
                dmsg => 's5410AC5F9800', state => 'T: 17.2 H: 47', user => 'NEUER'
      }
    ]
    },
    {name => 'Ventus W132', id => 4, data => [
      {
                dmsg => 'sD66EE1603000', user1 => 'dirigent', comment => 'wind',
                readings => [{ state => 'windGuest: 1.2 winddir:0' }]
      }
    ]
    },
],
);
```

I would like to sort this, that the value with the "id => 99" appears at the end.

I could sort all internal values ​​arbitrarily but I need the new outer sorting.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->sort_by` is used to control the order of the elements of hashes.

You want to control the order of the elements of an array.

There's no equivalent mechanism to `->sort_by` for arrays because there's no need for one. While you can't naturally control the order in which a hash returns its elements, you can naturally control the order in which an array returns its elements.

```
my $data = [ ... ];
@$data = sort { $a->{id} <=> $b->{id} } @$data;
print $json->encode($data);
```